# How can I use QMetaDataWriterControl to edit a Mp3 metadata?

Tags: qt, pyqt, metadata

I want to edit some mp3 files' metadata like title, album and etc.

I found `QMetaDataWriterControl` class that has `setMetaData()` function, but i don't know how can I use this class to do it.  any example is available?

edited: I wrote this code, but it's return None:

```
def _init__(self):
    filename="d:/1.mp3"
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    self.player=QMediaPlayer()
    self.player.metaDataAvailableChanged.connect(self.setMetaData)
    self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(url))


def setMetaData(self,b):
    s=self.player.service()
    x=s.requestControl('org.qt-project.qt.metadatawritercontrol/5.0') #return None
```

Comment: You'll get a pointer to an instance of this class through `QMediaService::requestControl(interface)`. The `QMediaObject` provides its service via `QMediaObject::service()` method.

Comment: what is interface? Isn't QMetaDataWriterControl available in pyqt?

Comment: Try using `QMetaDataWriterControl_iid` instead of the explicit interface name string. Other than that, the player's service may simply not implement that interface. It isn't something that pyqt controls, it's the underlying Qt that does it. Perhaps instead of using a `QMediaPlayer`, try a `QAudioDecoder`.